# How to merge nested map in terraform

Tags: terraform

I would like to merge locals values:

For now, I have this:

```
permission_defaults = {
  groups = {
    "group_1" = ["read"]
    "group_2" = ["read"]
    "group_3" = ["read"]
  }
}

permission_raw = {
  "prod" = {
    repositories = [
      "prod-repo",
    ]
  },
  "dev" = {
    repositories = [
      "dev-repo",
    ],
    groups = {
      "group_1" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
      "group_2" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
      "group_3" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
    }
  }
}

permissions = {
  for k, v in local.permission_raw : k => merge(local.permission_defaults, v)
}
```

So, basically it's some default permissions that I overwrite with specific values. This works well.

Now, I want to add a new permission that is the same as `dev`, *plus* something else:

```
permission_defaults = {
  groups = {
    "group_1" = ["read"]
    "group_2" = ["read"]
    "group_3" = ["read"]
  }
}

permission_raw = {
  "prod" = {
    repositories = [
      "prod-repo",
    ]
  },
  "dev" = {
    repositories = [
      "dev-repo",
    ],
    groups = {
      "group_1" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
      "group_2" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
      "group_3" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
    }
  }
  "dev-local" = {
    repositories = [
      "dev-local-repo",
    ],
    groups = {
      "group_1" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
      "group_2" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
      "group_3" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
      "group_4" = ["read", "delete", "write"]
    }
  }
}
```

This configuration works well but has the problem that if I update `dev` permissions I'll also have to update `dev-local`.

So, is there a way to merge dev and dev-local in order to just have `"group_4" = ["read", "delete", "write"]` for `dev-local.groups` ?

Thanks

Comment: If you want data this robust then you may want to use `external_data` instead of `locals`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source. Also you can do this, but it does not scale very well as it will be messy and of dubious cost/benefit.

Comment: I finally manage to find a solution:
Having 2 defaults permission block, one for prod one for dev.
I then do a first merge between devs, and a second one between dev and prod